# Empty EntityManager in Java EE bean on JBoss 5.1

Tags: jsp, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I'm a newbie in Java EE. This is the first project I'm trying to do and I have a problem that I just can't solve.

I've created three projects: slowka-beans (EJB), slowka-persistance (JPA) and slowka-web(JSF). After deploying them I can't get access to persistence unit - the EntityManager is null. Everything works fine - I can create beans, inside them instantiate entity classes and show them on JSF page. But how can I store them in the DB? I have MySQL database configured on JBoss site.

The code that I have looks following:
LanguagesManager.java (in slowka-beans)

```
@Stateless
public class LanguagesManager implements LanguagesManagerLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="slowka-persistance")
    private EntityManager em;

    public LanguagesManager() {
        System.out.println("LanguagesManagerBean constructor");
    }

    public String getWorking() {
        if(em == null) {
            System.out.println("Not working...");
            return "Not working...";
        } else {
            System.out.println("It's ALIVE!");
            return "It's ALIVE!";
        }
    }
}
```

persistence.xml (slowka-persistance):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="slowka-persistance">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/PraktykiDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>pl.edu.uj.sobczak.szymon.Language</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Deploying this on server doesn't cause any exceptions. but I've spotted the following warnings in server's output:

```
23:02:23,801 INFO  [PersistenceUnitDeployment] Starting persistence unit persistence.unit:unitName=slowka.ear/slowka-persistance.jar#slowka-persistance
23:02:23,803 INFO  [Ejb3Configuration] Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: slowka-persistance
    ...]
23:02:23,804 WARN  [Ejb3Configuration] Persistence provider caller does not implement the EJB3 spec correctly. PersistenceUnitInfo.getNewTempClassLoader() is null.
(... trimmed ...)
23:02:23,868 INFO  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] Bound factory to JNDI name: persistence.unit:unitName=slowka.ear/slowka-persistance.jar#slowka-persistance
23:02:23,868 WARN  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] InitialContext did not implement EventContext
```

Every time I'm accessing `LanguagesManager::getWorking()` from JSP i'm getting "Not working..." output.

I've created the project in Eclipse, JPA is using EclipseLink. I've tried both - EclipseLink 1.1.4 and 2.1.0 with the same result.

Can please you help me?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, and have spent days trying to solve this! Did you have any luck in the end? If so, would you please post a copy of your persistence.xml, and the relavent short code snippets from your servlet / bean

My question on stackoverflow is [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373598/how-to-use-container-managed-transaction-cmt-with-jboss-as-6-hibernate-3-6-jp

Answer (score 2):

Don't call EJBs from JSPs. Call them from servlets, where you inject them with `@EJB`.

If you instantiate the object manually, then injection does not happen. The object (ejb) must be instantiated by the EJB container.