# How to use Container Managed Transaction (CMT) with JBoss AS 6, Hibernate 3.6, JPA, JTA and EJB3

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, ejb-3.0, jta

I'm attempting to setup a web app using CMT. I've got it running standalone within Eclipse ok, and now I'm trying to get it working within Jboss AS 6, using Struts 1.0. I've chosen CMT because the doco I've read hints that it's the best and "least verbose to use". So seems like contempory/good-practice use of Hibernate 3.6.

I can load objects from a MySQL database with the following code extracts, but persisted objects are not being flushed/synchronised/saved to the database:

From within Struts 1.0 Action class:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();   
EntityManagerFactory emf = (EntityManagerFactory)ctx.lookup("java:/MyEntityManagerFactory");
```

'emf' is then passed to a method with my DAO class that is summarised below:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="purejetJPA") EntityManager em;
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
exampleMethodInMyCustomDAOClass() {
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.find(MyCustomEntity.class, 542);  // works successfully
em.persist(newInstanceOfMyCustomEntity);          // this executes ok and generates an ID
                                                  // however the entity is not saved to database upon completion 
}
```

Contents of persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myPersistanceUnitName" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
                <class>my.custom.entity.Classes</class>
                <properties>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/MyEntityManagerFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta"/>
        </properties>   
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The Hibernate EntityManager documentation has a very limited description of how to achieve CMT:

---

Our entity manager/transaction management idiom for CMT and EJB3 container-use is reduced to this:
    //CMT idiom through injection
    @PersistenceContext(name="sample") EntityManager em;

---

And this [jboss.org article](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/sessionsandtransactions#Transaction_demarcation_with_EJBCMT) says:

---

**Transaction demarcation with EJB/CMT**

Our goal really is to remove any transaction demarcation code from the data access code:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void doSomeWork() {

// Do some work
factory.getCurrentSession().load(...);
factory.getCurrentSession().persist(...);
}
```

---

My questions:

1. In the line "actory.getCurrentSession().load(...);", what type is "factory", and how do I create it? Is it Hibernate.SessionFactory? Or a Jboss or HTTP session?
2. In the line "@PersistenceContext(name="sample") EntityManager em;" what is "name" referring to? I found an example on a forum of something using "unitName" instead of "name".   Is this line how I first declare the EntityManager object that I use to call .persist() .find() etc? (and therefore my code that creates an EntityManagerFactory is not needed)
3. Should I consider researching and using "Java Context and Dependency Injection" (CDI)?

Any help much appreciated. Please let me know what other bits of code or config files I should supply

---

**Update:**

If I don't use EntityManagerFactory, and retrieve an EntityManager instead using @PersistenceContext, then should something like this code for my "session bean" (the class retriving+saving entities on a per-user-session basis) be the way to do it?

```
@Stateful
@TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class X implements IX {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="MySQL", type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager em;

@Resource
private UserTransaction tx;

public void doStuff() {
   tx.begin();
   em.joinTransaction();
   em.find(myEntity);
   em.perrsist(myEntity);
   tx.commit();
}
```

If this is on the right track, what is needed in persistence.xml? From all my reading of doco and the web I'm not sure which of these might be required:

```
<property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/MyEntityManagerFactory"/>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory"/>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) The answer is in the same document you linked :-)

> In the examples above you can see access to the SessionFactory. How do you get access to the factory everywhere in your code? Again, if you run in a Java EE environment, or use an embedded service in JSE, you could simply look it up from JNDI, where Hibernate can bind it on startup. Another solution is to keep it in a global static singleton after startup.

2) The `name` is a reference to the name specified in the tag `persistence-unit` from your `persistence.xml`. In your case, it's `myPersistanceUnitName`.

3) Yes, if you understand that it's not meant to replace anything, it's meant to facilitate the consumption of "beans" (which may be resources from the AS).

Also note that in order to get a managed EntityManager (with benefits), you should not get the EntityManagerFactory from the AS. You should get the EM itself. Like you mentioned, it's like this:

```
@PersistenceContext(name="myPersistanceUnitName") EntityManager em;
```

It will work only in things which are managed by the AS, like Servlets, other CDI beans, EJB, ... Not sure if Struts Action classes would get it injected :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was helpful! I don't think Struts has anything to do with things. It's merely the Servlet that's called on a per-user-session basis.  I've made updates to my question above.

Comment: For your newer questions: I'd say that the most common approach is to let the container manage the transactions. Every EJB method invocation is wrapped in a transaction by the container, unless you explicitly specify otherwise. That's the most common use case. Under the hoods, it uses JTA and the transaction context is "extended" to JPA transactions, and you won't need to specify anything in your code to take advantage of it. Again, you'll specify only if the default behavior is not the desired one.

Comment: Understood how the container will manage transactions. The EntityManager declared after @PersistenceContext is null, and I can't figure out why. I've add '@EJB', tried "=name" instead of "=unitName", but no luck.

Comment: Only WARN messages in STDOUT are: "[org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] Persistence provider caller does not implement the EJB3 spec correctly.PersistenceUnitInfo.getNewTempClassLoader() is null." and "[org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] InitialContext did not implement EventContext".

Comment: NOTE: Both those errors are also occuring in this person's question, which also remains un-solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319362/empty-entitymanager-in-java-ee-bean-on-jboss-5-1

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue. I have narrowed it down to when using `@WebService` and we inject the EntityManager via `@PersistenceContext`, the entitymanager is null.

Also if we delegate the data access to a DAO and add the `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)` for the DAO class, it throws the  `javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRequiredException`.

Wonder if this is a JBoss bug that does not add stateless session beans that have`@WebService` annotations to a container managed transaction.

Comment: On further investigation, the above was due to defining the web service in web.xml. When I removed it from web.xml everything works fine, We really don't need to define it in web.xml as jax-ws deploys it without any deployment descriptors. I defined it mainly to customize the webcontext.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I wasn't using @WebService anywhere though, so can you please explain how you think are issue is similar? And also what you recommend I do to solve my problem?